# Javascript - Object not a collection

Tags: javascript

i try to create an video object with activex but i take this error : "Object not a collection". This is my code and  error begins on line "this.parts = null;". There may be other things which causes error  before this line. I search on the Net about this error but there is no example to solve it.

```
function detailKeyPress(evt) {

        var evtobj=window.event? event : evt;
        switch (evtobj.keyCode) {
            case KEYS.OK:
                if (player.isFullScreen == false)
                    player.makeFullScreen();
                else
                    player.makeWindowed();                   
                break;

            case KEYS.PLAY:
                player.isPlaying = true;
                player.object.play(1);
                break;

            case KEYS.PAUSE:
                player.pause();
                break;

            case KEYS.STOP:
                player.makeWindowed();
                player.stop();
                break;
        }
    }

    function Player(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.object = document.getElementById(id);
        this.isFullScreen = false;           
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.parts = null;
        return this;
    }

    Player.prototype.play = function () {
        this.isPlaying = true;
        return this.object.play(1);
    }

    Player.prototype.playByUrl = function (url) {
        this.object.data = url;
        return this.play();
    }

    document.onkeydown = function (evt) {
        detailKeyPress(evt);
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        player = new Player('playerObject');
        player.playByUrl($mp4Link);
    }



    Player.prototype.makeFullScreen = function () {
        try {
            this.object.setFullScreen(true);               
            this.isFullScreen = true;               
        }
        catch (ex) {//If philips
            this.object.fullScreen = true;
            this.isFullScreen = true;
        }
    }

    Player.prototype.makeWindowed = function () {
        try {
            this.object.setFullScreen(false);
            this.isFullScreen = false;
        }
        catch (ex) { //If philips
            this.object.fullScreen = false;
            this.isFullScreen = false;
        }
    }

    Player.prototype.pause = function () {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.object.play(0);
    }

    Player.prototype.stop = function () {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.object.stop();
    }
```

Comment: yes it has. i think error begins before parts and stuck there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may caused by your registry. If you clean it, you can solve or probably a bug. I have searched also a lot about this error. There is no another thing to say.